# What is the Equivalent syntax of mysql “ LIMIT ” clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i know there is no `limit x,y` in sqlserver instead of it i use:

```
 select  ROW_NUMBER(),name OVER (ORDER BY name) AS
 myrow from pack  where myrow > 5 and myrow < 10
```

but it has following error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'myrow'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'myrow'.
```

any idea?

```
Edit
```

i saw [What is the Equivalent syntax of mysql " LIMIT " clause in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736563/what-is-the-equivalent-syntax-of-mysql-limit-clause-in-sql-server) but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Equivalent syntax of mysql " LIMIT " clause in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736563/what-is-the-equivalent-syntax-of-mysql-limit-clause-in-sql-server)

Comment: Did you try pasting your question title into Google?

Comment: @SLaks: that dupe is a bad answer to this question and generally

Comment: i see that page but have same error.

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine: you were getting there, just need to tweak syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (for 2005 and higher) -

```
SELECT p.name
FROM ( 
    SELECT  
          name
        , myrow = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)  
    FROM dbo.pack
) p
WHERE myrow BETWEEN 5 AND 9
```

Or try this (for 2012) -

```
SELECT name
FROM dbo.pack
ORDER BY name 
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine, second query only for `MS SQL 2012`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 there it the [OFFSET FETCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) syntax

However, for older versions you have to use ROW_NUMBER **but in a derived table**

```
select
    name
from
    (
    select
       name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS myrow
    from
       pack
    ) X
where
   myrow > 5 and myrow <= 10
```

Don't use 3 nested TOPs as per the suggested answer in the proposed duplicate