# Firebird rownum *or* linq style skip and take

Tags: sql, t-sql, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm using firebird database and it does not seem to have ROWNUM or ROW_NUMBER() like sql server does so I cannot follow the procedure explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744802/is-there-a-sql-equivalent-to-linq-skip1000-take100).

I have a query whose result dataset is bigger than what my system memory can accommodate. I'm trying load the dataset in smaller chunks. I have a series of generic queries which I cannot modify and they could be anything. I know I can do

```
select first 5000 * from
(-my actual query here-)
```

to get the first 5000 records. But how can I go about getting the next 5000 records.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since FireBird 2.0 `ROWS` syntax is supported, ie you would use

```
select * from tab ROWS m TO n
```

I suggest you download FB's [language reference update](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/Firebird-2.5-LangRef-Update.pdf) where it is documented.

Answer (score 3):

In firebird you use `Select First ? Skip ?` to specific how many, and what your offset is.

Comment: OH MY! Didn't think it would be this simple. this changes everything! thanks

Comment: Be careful using `first` in subqueries. There is a [documented bug](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-634) that is not fixed in 2.1.

Comment: In Firebird 2.0 and up the SQL-compliant ROWS syntax is available and should be used instead of the `FIRST ... SKIP`

Comment: @ain unless you want Select * skip 5000 from table.
You cannot duplicate that behavior with rows syntax. Not very common anyway.

Comment: @EMBarbosa You kind of can; quote from the doc: "You can often “fake
it” though, by supplying a second argument that you know to be bigger than the number of rows in the set".