# using Linq Skip Take for Traditional SQL Query rather using RowNum

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have the SQL Query in a string and am executing using the Traditional way of using DataAdapter.

Am trying to add pagination to the Existing logic. how do i add `Skip take` to the SQL string.

I know of using Skip and other linq methods for LINQ Queries. But is it possible to use for a SQL query in  a string format.

If yes how do i do it without adding RowNum to the query rather use skip and take.

```
Eg :

String sqlQuery = Select * from tablename ;
SqlDataAdapter com = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, Connection);
```

How do i use Linq methods on this SQL query for pagination rather going for `ROWNUM`

*Am not sure if am repeating the Question but i was not able to identify with the keywords

Thanks

Comment: Is it mysql or t-sql?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744802/how-do-i-write-linqs-skip1000-take100-in-pure-sql

Answer (score 3):

> How do i use Linq methods on this SQL query for pagination rather going for ROWNUM

You can't. You're issuing direct SQL - LINQ isn't involved here. LINQ will translate a query written in C# into SQL, but you can't start adding bits of LINQ to an existing SQL query. You should decide whether you *actually* want to write SQL, or whether you want to use LINQ. Then do just one at a time.

(You can use both in the same project, sure - but for a single query, you can't mix and match.)

Comment: Thanks @jon am dynamically forming the SQL query so i would go with ROWNUM.Any best approach for implementing with rownum  you can redirect to would be great !

Comment: @user2067567: That sounds like you should be asking a different question - at that point you're really only asking about SQL, with nothing to do with C# or LINQ.

Comment: Agree @jon !! ll see if i can find any :) Thanks  +1 solution