# Query to select data between row X and row Y in Stackexchange Data explorer

Tags: sql, t-sql, stackexchange, dataexplorer

I want to download the data from Stackexchange Data explorer but the problem is that the csv file contains only first 50K records at a time while there are about 3 Lac records.So, for downloading the whole data I will need to download it in multiple steps(first 1-50000 rows then 50001-100000 and so on).How can I specify such range(like row 50001-100000) in the query on the Stackexchange data explorer interface.I tried using TOP keyword(as Stackexchange data explorer supports TSQL) but with that I can get only first 50K records only.How can I use it to get next set of records?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience using Stackexchange Data explorer but, depending on which version of SqlSever it's using/emulating, you should be able to craft a query using OFFSET/FETCH (2012) or ROW_NUMER/OVER.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744802/how-do-i-write-linqs-skip1000-take100-in-pure-sql) for examples of each.

Reference for [OFFSET/FETCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER()/OVER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Looks like 2012 syntax is available...  see http://data.stackexchange.com/home%20improvementmeta/revision/141361/174020