# How to get the total page of LINQ pagination

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, paging, enumeration

Based on this answer on **[how to apply paging on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362144/how-to-apply-paging-on-a-list)**.

I would like to extend this question of how can we get the total page of a list with a specific total collection of item per page?

For example, suppose i have 50 items each page has 12 items. How can i get the total page?

Comment: Bit confusing, can you explain with an example?

Comment: With "total page", do you mean the number of the last page? e.g. "displaying page 1 of 14" and you want to get the "14"?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider yes sir that is what i mean sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it simple math?

> Page count = Round(Total Records / Page Size)

in C#

```
int totalItemCount = myList.Count();
int pageSize = 10;

int pageCount = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Ceiling(totalItemCount / System.Convert.ToDouble(pageSize)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know upfront how many records you have in total.

To do this simply use `yourquery.Count()`. It will translate to sql to some query beginning with `SELECT COUNT(*)...` and will not iterate over every single record.