# LINQ C# equivalent of LIMIT 0..10 MySQL with TAKE function

Tags: sql-server, linq

In MySQL you can limit a query row result with LIMIT 10,20

How is this possible with the Take(10) function in C#?

I have a 700000+ database table where I want to limit 10 rows each
and walk through the database table.

Comment: `.Skip(10).Take(10)`

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/548475/240733

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write LINQ's .Skip(1000).Take(100) in pure SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744802/how-do-i-write-linqs-skip1000-take100-in-pure-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) method

```
query.Skip(10).Take(10)
```

Comment: You made my day. My creator Almighty blessed you.