# SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have this query from mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
LIMIT 100, 200
```

Now how do I write similar query in SQL Server 2008. Basically I'm using php and SQL Server as backend and need to display records in range (1-100 then 100-200)

Comment: Not 100% familiar with `mysql` so not making this an answer, but wouldn't you just use `select top 100 * from table` to retrieve the first 100 records?

Comment: You need to use something to define the order. And paging can be done a number of ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql limit x, y equivalent for SQL Server l?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578643/mysql-limit-x-y-equivalent-for-sql-server-l)

Comment: I flagged this as a possible dupe because you're using SQL Server 2008. If you had 2012+, you'd have OFFSET FETCH available to you, which would be a different thing.

Comment: You know that Sql Server 2008 reaches end of life in less than 10 months, right? After that time, no new updates will be released... not even critical security patches. It's time to think about upgraded that server.

Comment: Also, the MySql `LIMIT` syntax is not part of the ansi standard.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SomeColumn, ...,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) AS RowNumber 
     FROM 
         table) Aux
WHERE 
    RowNumber >= @start AND RowNumber < (@start + @length)
```

Notes: You need mandatory order by a column and also you have to make a subquery to get access to `RowNumber` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Huh. For some reason I thought 2012 was the first version with windowing functions, but a check of the docs shows 2008 had them, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
SELECT ID, ItemID, ItemName, UnitCost, UnitPrice
FROM
(
SELECT     ID, ItemID, ItemName, UnitCost, UnitPrice,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UnitCost) AS Seq
FROM         dbo.Inventory
)t
WHERE Seq BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

you will basically use row_number to fetch they information that you need.