# Showing top 10 results in a table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able to show the items that has the top 10 highest values (quantity*price).
In MySQL you can use LIMIT, but that's not possible in SQL Server. How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT ItemID, Itemname, Quantity, Price,
CONVERT(Decimal(8,0),ROUND((Quantity*price),2)) AS Total
FROM Item
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulate MySQL LIMIT clause in Microsoft SQL Server 2000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000)

Comment: It's in yr title! SELECT TOP 10 ... ORDER BY q*p DESC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 10 ItemID, Itemname, Quantity, Price,
CONVERT(Decimal(8,0),ROUND((Quantity*price),2)) AS Total
FROM Item
ORDER BY Quantity * Price DESC
```

The `ORDER BY Quantity * Price DESC` will ensure that the highest values are returned first.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier than you think. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also just say `ORDER BY Total DESC` - since `ORDER BY` is processed last, it's the only place in a single query where you can refer to aliases in the `SELECT` list. Doesn't change the answer, just leads to slightly cleaner code.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT TOP 10 TItemID, Itemname, Quantity, Price,
CONVERT(Decimal(8,0),ROUND((Quantity*price),2)) AS Total
FROM Item
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 10 ItemID, ...
```

Maybe this will help you? Also look BOTTOM keyword.

Comment: `BOTTOM`? I think you're thinking of something other than SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe you have right, just said it from my memory wchich is not good.