# Why won't this PDOStatement execute properly?

Tags: php, pdo

I have other PDO Statements that execute fine, but this one is screwed up.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT ?,?' );
$sth->execute( array( 0, 10 ) );
```

The above does NOT work, but the below does work:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT 0,10' );
$sth->execute( array( 0, 10 ) );
```

So why won't the first way display any of my results when it should be giving the same response?

---

So here is what I have now

```
$start = 0;
$perpage = 10;

$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT ?,?' );
$sth->bindValue(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(2, $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

this also does not work

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT ?,?' );
$sth->bindParam(1, 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: can you change array( 0, 10, ) to array( 0, 10 ) and see if it works

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It still doesn't work without the second comma. :(

Comment: and the second comma was not a typo, php does not forbid it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that PDO will interpret any inputs as strings. You can try

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT :low,:high' );
$sth->bindValue(':low', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':high', 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Or

```
$low = 0;
$high = 10;
$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT :low,:high' );
$sth->bindParam(':low', $low, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':high', $high, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Source: [How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit)

Comment: Sounds like it would work but I get this error: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to change `bindParam` to `bindValue` I believe, in your answer @GlaciesofPacis

Comment: @PenguinCoder - Yep, I do. `bindParam` only works with parameters, while `bindValue` can either use a parameter or a value

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis I tried both snippets of code and neither returns any results. But if I simple change :low,:high to 0,10 it displays fine. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Just for fun, add a space after the comma, so `SELECT * FROM 'post' LIMIT :low, :high`

Comment: And don't worry @PenguinCoder, I'm a bit thrown off by your problems too!

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis Added the space and still the same result. Can you think of any other way to achieve this? I just want to control the start position and length of results...

Comment: @Dominick Hmm...you could just use `$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM post LIMIT ' . $low . ', ' . $high);` and not bind any parameters. You would NEED NEED ABSOLUTELY NEED to make sure that the $low and $high variables were numbers by using something like intval(). Just as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "prepare" and execute with array argument thinks your datas are string by default. So they escape them with ' '. THe problem is that when you deal with limits those quotes trigger error.
The solution is bindValue

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT :number OFFSET :start' );
$sth->bindValue("number",10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue("start",0,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: $start = 0;
    $perpage = 10;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT ?,?' );
    $sth->bindValue(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sth->bindValue(2, $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();

Still not working

Comment: why do you use 1 and 2 as index? I think 0 and 1 are the good ones. You can also use named parameters (for example :limit and :offset)

Comment: @artragis bindValue is actually 1-indexed (For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter). I agree that using named parameters is clearer though!

Comment: if the new code does not work it is that you have misspelled your table name. Check the case of "post", check the singular etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit) but have you tried casting the values you send as ints?

```
$start = 0;
$perpage = 10;

$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT ?,?' );
$sth->bindValue(1, (int)$start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(2, (int)$perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Or it says to do this:

```
$start = 0;
$perpage = 10;

$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM `post` LIMIT ?,?' );
$sth->bindValue(1, intval($start), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(2, intval($perpage), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

What database? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

In MySQL the PDO with `LIMIT` clause should work as in GlaciesofPacis's post. However, if you are using SQL SERVER you're not using the correct syntax. Referenced from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000) question:

```
$query = "
DECLARE @Sort
SET ROWCOUNT :startRow
SELECT @Sort = SortColumn FROM Table ORDER BY SortColumn
SET ROWCOUNT :pageSize
SELECT ... FROM Table WHERE SortColumn >= @Sort ORDER BY SortColumn
";

$dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->bindParam(':startRow',0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':pageSize',10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: It's MySQL. GlaciesofPacis' suggestion returns Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to change `bindParam` to `bindValue`.