# ANSI SQL version of SELECT TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, ansi-sql

Is there an ANSI SQL compliant version of SQL SERVER's `SELECT TOP n`?

Comment: Is there an option to ensure that [tag:sql-server] gives warnings for `Non-ANSI-SQL` commands? A [sql compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16) to set `ANSI` compliance would be great. But to my understanding there is no option like this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ANSI/ISO SQL:2003 introduced *windowing functions*:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY age ASC) AS rownum,
    person_id,
    person_name,
    age
  FROM person
) AS foo
WHERE rownum <= 3
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and later supports this syntax.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798(v=sql.90).aspx

ANSI/ISO SQL:2008 introduced a simpler syntax for `FETCH FIRST`, which may be more analogous to Microsoft/Sybase `TOP` syntax:

```
SELECT person_id, person_name, age FROM person
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and later supports this syntax.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned

If you're still using Microsoft SQL Server 2000, you should read a question I posted a while back about doing "paging" style queries:
[Emulate MySQL LIMIT clause in Microsoft SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000)

Comment: I did not even know that ROW_NUMBER() OVER was ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Some additional context, SQL Server has the following [`TOP` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
[   
    TOP (expression) [PERCENT]  
    [ WITH TIES ]  
]
```

The relevant standard SQL equivalents are:

```
FETCH FIRST expression ROWS ONLY
FETCH FIRST expression PERCENT ROWS ONLY
FETCH FIRST expression ROWS WITH TIES
```

Many SQL implementations only implement `ROWS ONLY`, in case of which the standard SQL equivalent would be to filter on:

```sql
-- PERCENT ROWS ONLY
percent_rank () OVER (ORDER BY ..) <= expression / 100

-- ROWS WITH TIES
rank () OVER (ORDER BY ..) <= expression
```

Answer (score -1):

'LIMIT' works with Amazon's Athena:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 3;
```

#### 3rd party edit

Quote from [athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/)

> Amazon Athena is a serverless, interactive analytics service built on
> open-source frameworks, supporting open-table and file formats. Athena
> provides a simplified, flexible way to analyze petabytes of data where
> it lives. Analyze data or build applications from an Amazon Simple
> Storage Service (S3) data lake and 25-plus data sources, including
> on-premises data sources or other cloud systems using SQL or Python.
> Athena is built on open-source Trino and Presto engines and Apache
> Spark frameworks, with no provisioning or configuration effort
> required.

Comment: Does athena strive to be "`query compatible`" to [tag:sql-server]?