# Limiting SQL Query to Just a Few Results

Tags: sql

I get over 1 million results from this query. How do I limit it to just the first 10 that I can test with?

```
Select id, first_name, last_name
from customers
Where country = 'US'
```

Comment: `fetch first 10 rows only`?

Comment: This depends on which specific SQL DBMS product you are using. For example in SQL Server you could use `TOP`. In MySQL the equivalent is `LIMIT`. Check your vendor's documentation for the correct thing to use, and for the exact syntax. You can also discover this kind of thing trivially by spending a few seconds using a search engine...what research have you done? We like answering interesting questions here, but we're less keen on just repeating information which is already readily available in many places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the results on a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128043/how-to-limit-the-results-on-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!
T-SQL

```
Select TOP 10 id, first_name, last_name
```

from customers
Where country = 'US'

For anything ANSI Compliant see this question which has a similar aim:
[ANSI SQL version of SELECT TOP 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804325/ansi-sql-version-of-select-top-1)