# Turn MySQL query to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in `MySQL`:

```
Select * 
From Customer 
Order By ID DESC Limit 1,1
```

How to use this query for `SQL server` ?

Comment: `Select top 1 * From Customer Order By ID DESC`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulate MySQL LIMIT clause in Microsoft SQL Server 2000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Customer
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RowNumber = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL, use this query to fetch Nth record

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY userID) AS ROW
FROM tblUser 
) AS TMP 
WHERE ROW = n
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1,1` returns the second record from the row set.

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server 2012` or higher, you can also use `Offset` and `Fetch`:

```
Select  * 
From    Customer 
Order By ID Desc 
Offset 1 Rows
Fetch Next 1 Rows Only
```