# SQL server - Limit search to a maximum value in a column

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a table that looks like the following;

```
version_number    ID    Value
1                 33    Foo
2                 33    Bar
1                 37    Foo
```

How would I return the Value field from the table if the ID was 33 and only select from the Maximum version number? (In this case, 2)

Something like;

```
SELECT Value FROM Table WHERE ID = 33 and MAX(version_number)
```

EDIT: Both answers below work. I'm going with Tim Schmelter's answer just because I think its a little more elegant, but I've up voted them both. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sql-server you can use ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER`, f.e. with a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT t.*, rn = Row_Number() Over (Partition By ID  Order By version_number Desc)
   FROM dbo.TableName t
)
Select Value From CTE
WHERE  ID = 33 
   AND rn = 1
```

Comment: that works if I want to specify the version_number, but I need it so it conforms to whatever the MAX is for the specified value. So for example, searching for ID 33 gets me the row with version_number 2, but searching for ID 37 gets me the row with version_number 1, if that makes sense?

Comment: @RyanHargreaves: it's working in that way. It will always return the row which belongs to the max-version number per ID (because of the `Partition By ID`). If you want to get the minimum version change `version_number Desc` to `version_number Asc`.

Comment: Sorry, your are correct, I forgot to order mine Desc. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery for this:

```
SELECT Value FROM
( SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM Table
  WHERE ID = 33 
  ORDER BY version_number
  ) as t
```

That is, start by getting the filtered data and then just print the desired column.

Comment: I want to return the Value, not the version number

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I translate that at the LIMIT keyword. Is that on SQL server?

Comment: @RyanHargreaves oh, I am coming from MySQL and am not fluent enough to the subtleties from SQL Server. [I see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/720280/1983854) `TOP 1` is the way here.

Comment: @RyanHargreaves:to avoid this please paste the expected result